# Can AutoHotKey be able to focus a panel?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, window, window-focus, title-bar

Some programs have floating panels within the main window. Since the ability to focus them with keyboard only depends on the framework they are using, is there a way to use AutoHotKey to do this instead?

For example, [PDF-XChange Viewer](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) has a bookmark panel. The panel has to be focused if I want to insert a bookmark with <kbd>Ins</kbd>, or selecting bookmarks with keyboard arrows. If not, the <kbd>Ins</kbd> key simply has no use, or the arrow keys move the current pages.

### With focus

The yellow in the title bar indicate that the panel is focused:

[image]

### Without focus

The panel isn't focused yet. Only clicking in the red box can focus it. Clicking on other locations (title bar, buttons, scrolling handle, moving it around) doesn't make it focused at all:

[image]

### Whole program

[image]

<sup>Related:

• [PDF viewers that can navigate bookmarks with keyboard only?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/52180/6389)

• [How to know the window manager a specific program uses?](https://superuser.com/q/1359209/301042)</sup>